# Including images in a Genshi/Trac template

Tags: html, image, xhtml, trac, genshi

I am trying to include some images in a Genshi template for my Trac plugin, but it always shows only the alternative text because it cannot find the images.

I have the following (X)HTML code:

```
<div>
  <img src="file://c:/path/to/image.png" alt="asdf" />
</div>
```

When I use this code with a simple html file and open it in the browser, the image is displayed correctly, which means that both the path and syntax are correct.

But when I insert the code snippet into a Genshi template and use it within Trac, the image cannot be found. However, when I look at the HTML source code in the web browser and copy the URLs into a new browser tab, it is again displayed correctly. This means that only the server cannot find the image.

The images are in a directory inside the python-egg file, and the path points directly to the directory created by Trac, which also contains my CSS and HTML files, both of which are loaded correctly. The images are correctly referenced in the setup script which creates the egg.

How do I have to reference images in (X)HTML documents when using them with a server? 
Is there a special way to include images in Genshi documents? (I haven't found one.)

Comment: In Trac you should use chrome-relative paths. To serve an image from your Environment `htdocs` directory, use `/chrome/site/image.png`, or see use the [available template variables](http://trac.edgewall.org/browser/tags/trac-1.0.9/trac/templates/about.html?marks=38#L33). For a plugin you should implement [ITemplateProvider](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.web.chrome.ITemplateProvider).

Comment: Do you mean, for a plugin I should implement ITemplateProvider "instead" of using the chrome class, or "additionally"? I already have my component implement ITemplate provider, and the path it returns is correct. Should I then call get_htdocs_dirs() myself, or is there a method to access the htdocs by letting Trac call the get_htdocs_dirs() method?

Comment: I misunderstood you there, I thought you meant the chrome class. Now using the correct path it works. I will write an answer below to explain what I've done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of RjOllos and [this site](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/TracURLs) I was able to fix it by trying all of the URL types. Although it says for a plugin to be `/chrome/<pluginname>`, it was actually just `/chrome` that worked. ***See the edit below!*** So the full URL is then `<ip>:<port>/chrome/path/to/image.png`.

**EDIT:** I discovered I actually used the `/chrome/pluginname` version, just that I did not use the name of my plugin as "pluginname". See my comment below. It seems like `/chrome/pluginname` should actually be `/chrome/htdocsname`or something like that, in case you use a different name rather than the plugin name when implementing the ITemplateProvider. In my case I called it `images`, which was the same name as the folder. **END OF EDIT**

Another mistake I made was forgetting the initial slash (`chrome/path/to/image.png`), which caused Trac to assemble the URL to `<ip>:<port>/<current page>/chrome/path/to/image.png`.

Comment: `/chrome/<pluginname>` is needed because `<pluginname>` is typically returned as the first entry of the tuple returned by the `ITemplateProvider.get_htdocs_dirs` implementation. Have you implemented [ITemplateProvider](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracDev/PluginDevelopment/ExtensionPoints/trac.web.chrome.ITemplateProvider) in your plugin?

Comment: Yes, I have. And using the plugin name in the URL caused an error which said that the file cannot be found.

Comment: I'd have to see your code to determine what the problem is. NoteBoxMacro is a simple example though, see [macro.py](https://trac-hacks.org/browser/noteboxmacro/trunk/notebox/macro.py?revision=13675&marks=62#L50) and [setup.py](https://trac-hacks.org/browser/noteboxmacro/trunk/setup.py?revision=13600&marks=17#L13).

Comment: I found the problem. I did not have the plugin name as first tuple item in the get_htdoc_dirs() method, but 'images' instead, because I thought it was convenient to return 'images' for images and 'css' for css files. Then, in the template, I added 'images' to the path, because I thought I had to give the path relative to the htdocs folder. So it was just a coincidence that I used the string 'images' in both cases. So instead of /chrome, I actually used /chrome/pluginname, just that pluginname was not the name of my plugin.